# Is there some different way to import RE in VS code or am I missing some settings?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, python-idle

Recently I wrote the following code...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay9W9.png)
Its working fine in Python IDLE. But in VS Code flags error saying "partially initialized module 're' has no attribute 'search' (most likely due to a circular import)".
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename is *re.py*, so your script is trying to import itself when you do `import re`.

Change your filename.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the name: `re.py`. Now when you do `import re` you are sort of importing your own file.

Changes your file's name to something else like `re_file.py`

Comment: I din't knew that was possible...